# prometheus occupies the JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc, prometheus, monitor, javaagents

I added Prometheus monitoring to my service.

> java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8
>   -javaagent:${base_dir}/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar=7030:${base_dir}/jmx_exporter/exporter_config.yml
>   -jar ${base_dir}/my-service.jar --spring.profiles.active=test

exporter_config.yml

> --- username: password:
>
> rules:
>   - pattern: ".*"

The service started to report error after running for a period of time.

> Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.alibaba.druid.pool.GetConnectionTimeoutException: wait millis 2000, active 20, maxActive 20

Turn off monitoring and return to normal.

Before I added monitoring, I confirmed that my service is normal.

Would you do me a favor?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the connection pool is getting exhausted for some reason. You can monitor the Druid connection pool ( your stacktrace  suggests you are using Alibaba Druid connection pool) by configuring `DruidStatInterceptor` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/alibaba/druid/wiki/%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE_Druid%E5%92%8CSpring%E5%85%B3%E8%81%94%E7%9B%91%E6%8E%A7%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE). Worth checking for any connection leaks happening.

Comment: 20 connections have been taken up, I suspect it is caused by Prometheus.